# Geo-referencing PNG with exact coordinates

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, georeferencing

For a bit of background, I am a novice when it comes to GIS stuff. I do a fair amount of geo-referencing of images but it has never had to be with exact coordinates like this project.

I am trying to geo-reference a PNG with exact coordinates which have been provided. It's for an event that features 3 tents California. We would like visitors to be able to walk around and use their phones to (roughly) geolocate themselves in the tents.

I have been provided 12 coordinates for each corner of each tent by the tent installers.

The issue I'm having is that when adding coordinates to the GCP points to the raster in the QGIS geo-referencer my points are dropping in the Atlantic Ocean off the coast of Africa. I suspect this is to do with how I've set up my CRS.

I was using the default WGS84 which was working to some extent and then changed it to 'NAD83/California Albers' which has messed everything up and now all points are dropping elsewhere in the world.

Is it the CRS or something else I'm missing?

Comment: In which coordinate system were your GCPs provided? You will have to choose the same CRS that matches your GCPs if you want to import/locate them correctly. And how exactly did you "change" the layer's CRS?

Comment: There are many valid coordinate systems for california, likely you picked the wrong one. Please provide a sample coordinate then the matching crs probably can be determined, or ask the person who provided the coordinates.

Comment: Adding a few screenshots will help a lot.

Comment: @FSimardGIS I changed the CRS in preferences of QGIS and then tried the geo-referencing. I've just freshly installed QGIS again.

link to coordinates and imagery provided: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1YHZdXo4jyh7a0C5J0L0ziMKr_BvvBmbR/view?usp=sharing

Comment: What coordinate system is your imagery using? If it's web Mercator (3857), that's why the coordinates show up off of Africa--that's where 0,0 is and the point values are small, relatively. You could try converting the dms to dd yourself (windows scientific calculator can do it) but you also need to identify them as lat/lon like 4326.

Comment: @mkennedy I don't know what system the image is using. I've asked them to provide more information, should I request a specific type of coordinate?

Answer (score 0):

I hate to be the bearer of bad news, but your "exact coordinates" are not good. The Decimal Degrees don't exactly match the DMS Degrees and neither are good enough to layout tent corners.
[image]

Comment: Thank you for confirming, I suspected there was an issue when I had tried. I can relay this to them. The tent isn't actually up yet so I suspect they have done this virtually.